# I had changed Plymouth theme to text-only, but want it back in Graphical mode

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth

How can I accomplish this? I am looking around in /usr/share/plymouth/themes and am about to gedit the default.plymouth file, to see if it's a property in there.

*later...*

nope, not it. Just a link to the theme I have just set. I have  gone in to change the theme using the sudo update-alternatives command, but it didn't do anything. I still get the text-only boot. Can anyone help me find out how to revert to graphical mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverse engineered the process I did to switch to the text interface on boot, and for the record, will be answering my own question.

Open terminal:

`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

and change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

then do `sudo update-grub2`

and `reboot` (or combine the two with `sudo update-grub2 && reboot`).

Again, I am just posting an answer to my own question for the record so it can possibly help someone else in this position.

Comment: ah, yes the 'quiet slash' is required. I was thinking you had changed to a text plymouth theme, not changed to the console mode.

Answer (score 2):

the commands for the new Plymouth configuration are:

```
sudo plymouth-set-default-theme -l  #this lists installed themes
sudo plymouth-set-default-theme <theme name>  # this sets theme
```

After setting theme you have to update initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly :3 It's amazing how quickly people respond on here. Wish it were the same everywhere...